# Using Javascript to Toggle CSS Display Setting

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a page where I can post a series of long text (in this particular case, song lyrics). I've followed the code from site doing similar things, but cant seem to make it work. any suggestions? My code is posted below.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <script>
         <!--
        function toggle(ID) {
            var x = document.getElementById(ID); //get lyrics element
            var xdisplay = x.style.display;    // get CSS display settings

            //Change CSS display setting
            if (xdisplay == none) {
                xdisplay = "block"
            }
            else {
                xdisplay = "none"
            }
            -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="toggle(l1)" id="lyric1">Click Here for Lyrics</button><br>
    <button onclick="toggle(l2)" id="lyric2">Click Here for Lyrics</button><br>
    <button onclick="toggle(l3)" id="lyric3">Click Here for Lyrics</button><br>

    <p class=lyric id=l1> Lyrics 1 </p>
    <p class=lyric id=l2> Lyrics 2 </p>
    <p class=lyric id=l3> Lyrics 3 </p>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.lyric {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You're missing quotations all around your code.
2. You're not passing valid id's, you're passing variable names instead of strings.
3. To get a css rule that was set in css, use `getComputedStyle` instead of `style`.
4. To change the style, don't use the string that holds the current one, instead use the style attribute.

```js
function toggle(ID) {
  var x = document.getElementById(ID); //get lyrics element
  var xdisplay = getComputedStyle(x, null).display; // get CSS display settings
  //Change CSS display setting
  //Change x.style.display, not xdisplay
  if (xdisplay == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.lyric {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle('l1')" id="lyric1">Click Here for Lyrics</button><br> <!-- changed l1 to 'l1' -->
<button onclick="toggle('l2')" id="lyric2">Click Here for Lyrics</button><br> <!-- changed l2 to 'l2' -->
<button onclick="toggle('l3')" id="lyric3">Click Here for Lyrics</button><br> <!-- changed l3 to 'l3' -->

<p class="lyric" id="l1"> Lyrics 1 </p> <!-- changed l1 to "l1" and lyric to "lyric" -->
<p class="lyric" id="l2"> Lyrics 2 </p> <!-- changed l2 to "l2" and lyric to "lyric" -->
<p class="lyric" id="l3"> Lyrics 3 </p> <!-- changed l3 to "l3" and lyric to "lyric" -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Tag on question, is it possible to restore the display setting for l1 when another button is pressed?

Comment: @M.Winter If by restore you mean `display:none`, use a condition: `if (ID !== 'l1') { x.style.display = 'none'; }`.

Comment: The use of xdisplay fixed a problem I had with the use of display in the recommended toggle code used at W3School. With the W3Schools code, the first button click was ignored, but subsequent clicks toggled display OK.  By using xdisplay, the first click works properly. And that's why you got an up-vote after all this time. Thanks, @MrGeek !

Answer (score 0):

You are copying the value of `x.style.display` to `xdisplay`, and then setting `xdisplay` to other values. Instead, try:

```
if (xdisplay == "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong codes, as you missed some quotation marks and  a curly bracket ,

First solve your syntax errors then , try this js code it works fine:

```
    function toggle(ID) {
        var x = document.getElementById(ID); 
        var xdisplay = x.getAttribute("class");  

        if (xdisplay) {
            x.removeAttribute("class");
        }
        else {
            x.setAttribute("class", "lyric");
        }
    }
```